# How can I make the Metronic calendar change its language based on user selection among several languages?

Tags: calendar, onchange, lang, metronic

I use the Metronic theme and the calendar is always in English by default. There are 5 languages in my system and I want it to change according to whichever of these languages is selected. How can I do this?

I used things like full-lang.js but no results